# Different behavior of 'between' operator in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I  know  ' between'  operator is  inclusive for ranges   specified..but  in  following  case it  works differently

I  have  table customer with  following  attributes.

```
  customer 
    {
     customername  varchar2(30),
      custid  integer(10,0)

    }
```

Query

```
   select *  from customer c where  c.customername between  'a'  and 'b';
```

Above query fetches  data only customer name  starting  with 'a'. But
when  we  use  'between'  operator  with  number   in that case  both are  inclusive.Could  anyone  explain me  this  bahvior.

Comment: Try inserting a customer whose name is exactly 'b'. See if you can figure it out.

Comment: @Mat  if  i  change  query    between 'a' and  'c'..it  will all   fetch  result starting  from  a and b..i want  to  know   why  between operator  behavior  is different...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not different. `BETWEEN` is still inclusive. However you should keep in mind that string comparison in programming is a little bit more complicated than integer comparison. In the database strings are ordered like this:

```
'a' < 'andy' < 'andy1' < 'anna' < 'b' < 'boris' < 'brian'.
```

So `between  'a'  and 'b'` will return:

```
'a', 'andy', 'andy1', 'anna', 'b'
```

But since you don't have a customer named exactly `'b'` you get only:

```
'a', 'andy', 'andy1', 'anna'
```

If you want only those customers whose name starts with a or b you should use [SUBSTR](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2101.htm#OLADM679):

```
select *  from customer c where  SUBSTR(c.customername, 1, 1) between  'a'  and 'b';
```

Answer (score 4):

The [`BETWEEN`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/conditions011.htm#SQLRF52147) operator acts as:

> And the value of
>
> ```
> expr1 BETWEEN expr2 AND expr3
> ```
>
> is the value of the boolean expression:
>
> ```
> expr2 <= expr1 AND expr1 <= expr3
> ```

It works the same way for character strings as for numbers, but you have to think about it a bit more for strings.

In particular:

```
 'a'  <= 'b' // true
 'ab' <= 'b' // true
 'b'  <= 'b' // true
 'ba' <= 'b' // FALSE
```

If you had a customer with the name exactly `b` in your dataset, it would be returned by your `between` query. But `bob` wouldn't be returned, because `'bob' <= 'b'` is false.